# data from useSelector cause infinite re-render as a dependency

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, redux-thunk

I am doing a simple CRUD using redux-thunk.

Everything works fine, I obtain data from store ,like this and I render it in a table component.

Table component excerpt

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { getItems } from '../actions/actions'
import ButtonCreate from '../components/buttons/ButtonCreate'
import ButtonDelete from '../components/buttons/ButtonDelete'
import ButtonUpdate from '../components/buttons/ButtonUpdate'

export const Table = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const { data } = useSelector(state => state.axiosDataReducer)
    console.log(data)

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getItems())
    }, [dispatch])


    return (
        <div className='container mt-5 mb-5'>
            <ButtonCreate />
            <table className="table table-striped table-hover caption-top ">
                <caption>Online Store</caption>
                <thead className='table-dark'>
                    <tr className='text-center'>
                        <th scope="col">Id</th>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Cost</th>
                        <th scope="col">Category</th>
                        <th scope="col">Department</th>
                        <th scope="col">Update</th>
                        <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        data?.map((x, index) => (
                            <tr key={x.id}>
                                <th scope="col">{index + 1}</th>
                                <th scope="col">{x.name}</th>
                                <th scope="col">$ {x.cost?.toFixed(2)}</th>
                                <th className='text-center'>
                                    {
                                        x.category.map((y, index) => (
                                            <span key={index * 0.125}>{y.name}</span>
                                        ))
                                    }
                                </th>
                                <th className='text-center'>
                                    {
                                        x.department.map((z, index) => (
                                            <span key={index * 0.225}>{z.name}</span>
                                        ))
                                    }
                                </th>
                                <th><ButtonUpdate id={x.id} /></th>
                                <th><ButtonDelete id={x.id} /></th>
                            </tr>
                        ))
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    )
}
```

This is the fetchdata function in action:

```
// get items
export const getItems = () => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(baseURL);
            const data = response.data;
            dispatch({
                type: types.get,
                data: data
            });
        } catch (error) {
            return dispatch(
                {
                    type: types.error,
                    msg: "Unable to get items"
                });
        }
    };
};
```

But when I delete one item I want that the Table component re-render one time showing the new table with the lack of the deleted value. So, when I configure the useEffect with data it re-renders infinitely.

```
useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getItems())
    }, [dispatch,data])
```

I just want that the component render one time cause the length of the data changes but it doesn t do anything (data?.length), showing the new tabla

How can I avoid this? of course I can use a sort of page reloading but it seems this is not the solution.

I have read about memo, useMemo and useCallback but I do not know how to configure it in this case scenario.

I am adding the reducer:

```
import { types } from "../types/types";

const initialState = {
    data: null,
    selected: null,
    deleted: '',
    created: null,
    modified: null,
    error: ''
}

export const axiosDataReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.get:
            return {
                ...state,
                data: action.data
            }
        case types.selected:
            return {
                ...state,
                selected: action.selectedItem
            }
        case types.delete:
            return {
                ...state,
                deleted: action.deletedItem
            }
        case types.created:
            return {
                ...state,
                created: action.createdItem
            }
        case types.modified:
            return {
                ...state,
                modified: action.modifiedItem
            }

        case types.error:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.msg
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

and also the actions for deleting:

```
//delete item
export const selectItem = (id) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${baseURL}${id}`);
            const data = response.data;
            dispatch({
                type: types.selected,
                selectedItem: data
            });
        } catch (error) {
            return dispatch(
                {
                    type: types.error,
                    msg: "Unable to select item for delete"
                });
        }
    };
}

const sweetAlertConfirmDeleteItem = (id, dispatch) => {
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
    })
        .then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                axios.delete(`${baseURL}${id}`);
                dispatch({
                    type: types.delete,
                    deletedItem: 'Item deleted'
                })
                Swal.fire(
                    'Deleted!',
                    'Your file has been deleted.',
                    'success'
                )
            }
        })
}

export const getItemDeleteGetItems = (id) => {

    return async (dispatch) => {

        try {
            dispatch(selectItem(id))
            sweetAlertConfirmDeleteItem(id, dispatch)


        } catch (error) {
            return dispatch(
                {
                    type: types.error,
                    msg: "Unable to delete item"
                });
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Looks like the way you are deleting the item is not correct . Can you add your reducer code  where you are doing the delete ?

Comment: the delete works ok, in my opinion of course, i want the table refetch the data just once, as a result of the deleting, not infinitly

Comment: Hmm this looks bit confusing , if it is a table then i suppose the data has to be a list , but here we have an object . Are am i missing some details here ? when deleting a item we are supposed to remove it from the `data` right ? But i don't see we are doing that here .

Comment: my bad, editting the table component

Comment: Where in your snippet(s) do you attempt to delete anything? Is the `Table` component being remounted for some reason? Can you share how `Table` is being rendered, the props passed to it or if it's being conditionally rendered, etc...?

Comment: I edited my post, please verify

Comment: in table useEffect is where I've tried to use data as a dependency, but rerender infinitly, i just want to rerender once after delet the item

Comment: Right, and something is causing the effect to run and dispatch `getItems` action. Since `dispatch` is a stable reference it can't retrigger the effect. I suspect your `Table` component is remounting.

Comment: yes, is remounting when I add data as a dependency, visually the above fix my problem cause when i  delete the item and show the table updated, but i  know has a lot of rerenders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `sweetAlertConfirmDeleteItem` when dispatching the delete action dispatch it like this ,

```
dispatch({
  type: types.delete,
  deletedItem: { id }
})
```

Now in your reducer you can do this, once you get the deleted item , remove it from the data.

```
case types.delete:
            return {
                ...state,
                data: state.data.filter(item => item.id !== action.deletedItem.id),
                deleted: action.deletedItem
            }
```

Also remove the `data` as a dependency from the useEffect .

Comment: this make sense, ...trying and comebacking with results

Comment: i did it as you told, still not rerender the one time i want after deleting showing that my table has one less value :(

Comment: I see you have a console.log(data) in the component where you are rendering the table . After delete , do you still see the deleted item getting printed in that console log  ? . Also check in the redux - devtools whether the action to delete is dispatched correctly . Also you can add console logs inside your reducer and check whether the case for delete is executed .

Comment: all is fine(as I figure it of course). nothing happend if I've deleted the item the table doesn t auto-change. for instance, I delete the item, redux dev tools show the acurate messages..but I need to press F5 to see the new table...that is why the data dependency

Comment: oho ho..check this out...as @Shyam sugested but instead of :
case types.delete:
            return {
                ...state,
                data: state.data.filter(item => item.id ! == action.deletedItem.id),
                deleted: action.deletedItem
            }
i did 
case types.selected:
            return {
                ...state,

                data: state.data.filter(item => item.id !== action.selectedItem.id),
                selected: action.selectedItem
            }

and it totaly worked but it's a bit against the logic i 've created

Comment: Instead of updating the data in the selected item action . You should be using the delete action . Because the selected item action gets fired before even you make the API call to delete the selected item . Consider this scenario, you have selected an item , it got deleted but the api call got failed , in this case we are not showing incorrect data to the user . So its better to do the filtering in the delete action as it gets fired only when the api call is successful . I am updating my answer :-) please take a look .

Comment: yesssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss.thanks a lot, but tell me, why is this happened this way if my useeffect ...i need to understand

Comment: The reason your useEffect was running infinite times is you called getItems which updates the `data` . Now if you add that `data` as a dependency . The flow will be like . call getItems update data -> now you get new data -> since data is dependency -> useEffect will run again -> you call getItems -> get new data -> and this continues . So a rule of thumb is if you are updating some state in the useEffect then that should not be part of your useEffect dependency .

Comment: okok..I thought that i will fix the re render using something like useCallback, useRef, memo, or useMemo..i was mistaken..okok

Answer (score 0):

what i did was as fallow

I split the UpdateItem.js component in two

one obtaining data from useSelect and rendering data if select!==null
the other to be in charge with the form and receiving props

UpdateItem.js is now like this:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React from 'react'

import { useForm } from '../hooks/useForm'
import { baseURL } from '../configuration/baseURL'

import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { types } from '../types/types';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

import Swal from 'sweetalert2'


export default function UpdateItem({ id, name, cost, departmentName, departmentIdentification, categoryName, categoryId }) {

    const history = useHistory()

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const [formValues, handleInputChange] = useForm({

        newName: name,
        newCost: cost,
        newDepartmentName: departmentName,
        newDepartmentIdentification: departmentIdentification,
        newCategoryName: categoryName,
        newCategoryId: categoryId
    })

    const {
        newName,
        newCost,
        newDepartmentName,
        newDepartmentIdentification,
        newCategoryName,
        newCategoryId } = formValues

    const handleUpdateItem = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
            await axios.put(`${baseURL}${id}`, {
                "id": +id,
                "name": newName,
                "cost": +newCost,
                "department": [
                    {
                        "name": newDepartmentName,
                        "identification": newDepartmentIdentification
                    }
                ],
                "category": [
                    {
                        "name": newCategoryName,
                        "id": +newCategoryId
                    }
                ]
            })
            const modified = await axios.get(`${baseURL}${id}`)
            const { selected } = modified

            dispatch({
                type: types.modify,
                modifiedItem: selected
            });
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'Your item has been modified',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 1500
            })
            setTimeout(() => {
                history.push('/')
            }, 1500);

        } catch (error) {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: 'Something went wrong!',
                footer: 'Unable to modify item, who passes the id?'
            })
            return dispatch({
                type: types.error,
                msg: 'Unable to modify item'
            })
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className='container mt-5 mb-5 pb-3 bg-light'>
            <form className='mt-3' onSubmit={handleUpdateItem}>

                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Name'
                    placeholder='Name'
                    name='newName'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newName}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Cost'
                    placeholder='Cost'
                    name='newCost'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newCost}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Department Name'
                    placeholder='Department Name'
                    name='newDepartmentName'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newDepartmentName}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Department Identification'
                    placeholder='Department Identification'
                    name='newDepartmentIdentification'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newDepartmentIdentification}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Category Name'
                    placeholder='Category Name'
                    name='newCategoryName'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newCategoryName}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Category Id'
                    placeholder='Category Id'
                    name='newCategoryId'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newCategoryId}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />

                <button className='btn btn-success ' type=' submit'>
                    Modify Item
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and the new component called ConditionalRenderUpdateItem.js like this

```
import React from 'react'

import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import UpdateItem from '../screen/UpdateItem';


export default function ConditionalRenderUpdateItem() {

    const { selected } = useSelector(state => state.axiosDataReducer)

    const id = selected?.id
    const name = selected?.name
    const cost = selected?.cost
    const departmentName = selected?.department[0].name
    const departmentIdentification = selected?.department[0].identification
    const categoryName = selected?.category[0].name
    const categoryId = selected?.category[0].id
    return (
        <div>
            {(selected !== null) &&
                <UpdateItem
                    id={id}
                    name={name}
                    cost={cost}
                    departmentName={departmentName}
                    departmentIdentification={departmentIdentification}
                    categoryName={categoryName}
                    categoryId={categoryId}
                />}
        </div>
    )
}
```